# Invariant factors don't depend on base field

Tags: linear-algebra

Could someone please explain why the invariant factors of an operator on a finite dimensional vector space do not depend on the base field. This fact isn't given in my textbook, and i'm having some trouble finding a reference online. Thank you.

By invariant factors, I mean the polynomials related to the invariant subspaces in the rational canonical form of the operator. That is, we can write the vector space $V$ as $V=Z(\alpha_1,T)\oplus...\oplus Z(\alpha_n,T)$, where each $Z(\alpha_i,T)$ is a cyclic subspace generated by $\alpha_i$, and the invariant factors are the polynomial $p_i$ that are the unique monic polynomials that generate the polynomial ideal $\langle p_i\rangle=\{g\in\mathbb{F}[x]:g(T)\alpha_i=0\}$

Comment: I know what invariant factor of a module is. What is invariant factor of an operator? Also, what does it mean to say it doesn't depend on a base field?

Comment: No wonder you don't find reference: please be **precise** on what you mean by "invariant factors of operator" on f.d. space. For example, two rather well known invariants are the trace and the determinant...and these **indeed** do not depend on the field the operator is defined...Anything else?